# Serializable save game function not working

Tags: java, serialization, serializable

I am trying to save a game state with no success.

```
public void saveGame(){
board = GameBoard.this;

try (
  OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(board);    <---- error in this line
  OutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream(file);
  ObjectOutput output = new ObjectOutputStream(buffer);
){
  output.writeObject(game);
}  
catch(IOException ex){
  fLogger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Cannot save.", ex);
}

}
```

The error I receive for the line indicated is that it is not a suitable constructor.  I'm completely lost. Can someone help me get this working or give me pointers as to where I have gone wrong please. I am not familiar with serializeable.

Comment: Can you tell us the type of the `board` variable?

Comment: private GameBoard board; < it is the object GameBoard this is the only class i am using .

Comment: What do you expect it to do with that object?  I thought you wanted to write to a file?

Comment: I don't know the correct procedure but ideally id like to save the games state.

Comment: Your edits made this question meaningless. NB when you get an exception, print it. Not some random message of your own devising. And this doesn't really have anything to do with serialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html for the constructors of FileOutputStream. The first one will do perfectly fine:

`OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("/path/object.dat"));`

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the `FileOutputStream` with a `File` to work with:

```
OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("pathToMyFile.txt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) you can read that there are 2 one parameter constructors:

```
FileOutputStream(File file)
FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor fdObj)
FileOutputStream(String name)
```

so since your compiler complains and I have no idea what `GameBoard` is (which you feed your constructor with) check if your `GameBoard` is by any chance of these. If not then you should do something about it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation fo `FileOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html), there are a few constructors for the `FileOutputStream` class:

1. [Using a `File` object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File))
2. [Using a `File` object and a boolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File,%20boolean))
3. [Using a `FileDescriptor` object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.FileDescriptor))
4. [Using a `String` object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.lang.String))
5. [Using a `String` object and a boolean value](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.lang.String,%20boolean))

Since you're using a constructor which you supply with one parameter, you're using either option 1, 3 or 5. The `board` variable has type `GameBoard`, which is not `File`, `FileDescriptor` or `String`, so the compiler tells you there is no constructor that matches the type of variable `board`.

The easiest is to give the `FileOutputStream` constructor a filename to write to. Other options are a `File` object or a `FileDescriptor`.

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the javadocs, `FileOutputStream` expects a `String` or `File`  The error message is trying to tell you, you are trying to pass an object to the constructor it doesn't support.

I suggest you give it to filename you want it to write to.

Other suggestions

- You don't need to buffer an ObjectOutputStream as it is already buffered.
- When you have a buffered stream you should always close (or flush it) otherwise you will have unwritten data, possibly the file will be empty.